# Angular CORS Issue When Making Multiple Requests Consecutively

Tags: node.js, angular, express

i am using Angular 6 and i have a node api backend.

Iam getting a cors issue but it only happens occasionally.

Every 5 seconds i am doing a http get request

```
   const url = 'https://<removed>.com/api/v1/transactions/' + transactionId;

    interval(5000)
        .pipe(
            switchMap(() => this.httpClient.get(url)),
            tap((response: any) => {
                this.summary = response;
            }),
            takeWhile((response: any) => response.data['status'] !== 'Completed'),
    ).subscribe();

}
```

The first request is fine, then i get the following error on the next request.

> Failed to load
>   https://"".com/api/v1/transactions/f3debad2-a830-4168-9a03-475389dae7e0:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 502.
>
> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response
>   https://"".com/api/v1/transactions/f3debad2-a830-4168-9a03-475389dae7e0
>   with MIME type text/html. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more
>   details.

Again this only happens sometimes, other times i can make as many requests i want with 200 responses.

In my node backend i have, before all my routes.

```
this.app.use(cors());
```

Comment: Hey man, have you fixed this issue already? I'm experiencing it now right now, On my backend I have set the CORS properly but I'm still getting a CORB error when making a multiple request to different urls, so I'm not sure what else should I add.

Comment: @SherwinAblañaDapito not yet i havent had a chance to test anything, let me know if u find a solution

Comment: Okay cool, I will assume you're using Request module on the backend, Have you tried adding followRedirect: false? Your request might be bouncing somewhere. Or you could try using Method HEAD instead of GET on the backend (For testing) and see what would happen. I hope this help you somehow.

Comment: @SherwinAblañaDapito did you fix your problem ,if so how? and yes i am using Request module on the backend.

Comment: I haven't fixed the problem yet but I added a temporary fix. The CORB issue appear on my end when my HTTP request takes too long to finish or if there's too many redirects but no error. So what I did was, I added a timeout option in request module and it somehow fix the CORB issue.

Comment: @SherwinAblañaDapito i think i have a similar issue could you please provide that solution as an answer with code snippet and i will take a look? thanks. My error above also says CORB

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will solve your CORB issue. I added a timeout as a temporary fix for my CORB issue. My CORB issue appears if my http request takes too long to finish or if there's too many redirect

> sample: If I make a multiple request to (http://www.redbull.com, http://www.redbull.org, http://www.redbull.net, and so on) other extension might redirect to .com and if takes too long I get the CORB error similar to yours

so what I did was I added timeout

```
// set request option
const requestOption = url => {
    return {
       url      : url,
       method   : 'HEAD',
       json     : true,
       timeout  : 5000,
       headers  : { 'connection': 'Keep-Alive' }
    }
}

// initialize request
const initializeRequest = (callback, option) => {
    request(option, (error, response, result) => {
      // for undefined response
      if(!response)
          return callback(null, response === undefined ? 404 : 200)

      callback(error, response.statusCode);
    }); 
}

// on your controller
module.exports.executeRequest = (req, res) => {
    //call initialize request here and create error handler.
    initializeRequest(your callback, requestOption(your URL));
}
```